# Why is the value of closing bracket character sometimes not ')' after reading input from std::cin?

Tags: c++

I'm running through some C++ tutorials, and I've hit what is probably a trivial issue but is stumping me right now. When I output the value of a closing bracket character in C++ using Xcode 11.3, it sometimes outputs as what looks like a unicode character.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int x;
    char ch1, ch2;

    std::cin >> ch1 >> x >> ch2;

    if (!std::cin || ch1 != '(' || ch2 != ')') {
        std::cout << "FAIL:\n";
        std::cout << "ch1 = " << ch1 << "\n";
        std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
        std::cout << "ch2 = " << ch2 << "\n";
        return 1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "SUCCESS:\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In Xcode, the input `(2)` - inputted as four keystrokes "(", "2", ")" and ENTER - gives the output:

```
FAIL:
ch1 = (
x = 2
ch2 = \357
```

However if the closing bracket is used as the first character in the stream, it outputs as the character `)`, as expected.

I'm guessing it something to do with how things are escaped, or possibly some logical error around how I'm using the input stream. Please could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2e51a9e484ec45)

Comment: Hmm strange. I wonder if it's something to do with Xcode? - I'm typing four keystrokes "(", "2", ")", then ENTER.

Comment: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YAQCDN) approves too.

Comment: What happens if you copy the input from somewhere(TextEdit maybe) and paste it then ENTER?

Comment: \357 is octal for 0xEF, which suspiciously is the first byte of a byte order mark used to signify endianness in utf8. I wonder if the sequence 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF is being used. Can you try making ch2 a char[4] and trying `*ch2 != ')'` ?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `*(ch2 + 3) != ')'` which will fail on other compilers but may identify the bug.

Comment: If I paste the string "(2)" from TextEdit, then hit ENTER it works! Annoying but I can live with it.

Allan - I'm not sure how to make ch2 a char[4]. If I try to use this in a declaration I get "Brackets are not allowed here; to declare an array, place the brackets after the name." 

Apologies, I'm working through C++ Principles and Practice and haven't reached pointers etc yet.

Comment: @AlexH If you manually type `(2)` into a stringstream in your program, does it also display the same strangeness? You can copy [this](https://godbolt.org/z/AWa7AW) and then remove `(2)` and type it back in manually to test it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I copy your program into Xcode, then delete and retype the `(2)` it works correctly. So I think it must have something to do with inputting characters into the terminal / standard input manually.

Comment: I think I know what it is. When I type into the input stream, Xcode autocompletes the closing bracket. Obviously I wasn't taking notice of this until just now, and the input appeared correct, but obviously there was no actual keystroke. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

When I type into the input stream, Xcode autocompletes the closing bracket. Obviously I wasn't taking notice of this until just now, and the input appeared correct, but obviously there was no actual keystroke.

Comment: What a strange behaviour. I wonder what it's actually inserting into the stream.

Comment: Where do you actually type this?

Comment: In the Target Output window at the bottom of Xcode. I agree it's very confusing and seems like it would be unhelpful most of the time.

Comment: Sounds like it!!